# Writing in the Data Area of ARM

Tags: arm, stm32, keil

I am writing a bubble sort in ARM Assembly on the STM32.

```
    AREA  Data1,DATA,READWRITE
```

ARR  DCD  1,3,2,4

How can I write a value to the array in the data area? I am using LDR,=ARR to load the address of ARR. However, when I check the memory, the values are all zero.

```
    AREA   main, CODE, READONLY
    EXPORT __main 

__main
    MOV R4,#4; LENGTH OF ARRAY
    MOV R5,#3; NUMBER OF ITERATIONS
    MOV R6,#3;  NUMBER OF COMPARISONS
    LDR R0,=ARR; ADDRESS OF ARR[0] FROM DATA AREA

__LOOP1
    CMP R5,#0
    BEQ __done
    CMP R6,#0
    BEQ __L2;
    LDR R2,[R0,#4]; R2=ARR[i+1]
    LDR R1,[R0]; 
    MOV R3,R1;
    CMP R1,R2;
    BLE __L1;
    STR R2,[R1];
    STR R3,[R0];
__L1        
    SUBS R6,#1;
    ADDS R0,#4;
    B __LOOP1;
__L2
    SUBS R5,#1;
    MOV R6,R5;
    LDR R0,=ARR;
    B __LOOP1;
 __done

    AREA  A,DATA,READWRITE
ARR  DCD  1,3,2,4 

    END
```

Comment: how are you loading the program.  the sram is volatile, so typically your .data goes in flash and then on boot you copy it to ram

Comment: Do you mean loading the main? I am using keil so the startup file will do the loading

Comment: @old_timer I have added my code here can you help me check what's wrong with my code? How can I write into the array?